# Recreating Global 3D Points, from Local 3D Points and Global 2D Points; SolvePnP

Tags: python, opencv, graphics, 3d

Aloha,
i have a list of 2D Keypoints which are located in the global scope/frame (image points), and a list of corresponding 3D Keypoints in the local scope (often called texture or object points). The image points are ranging from x[0-1920]y[0,1080] and the object points are withing the range of x[-1,1]y[-1,1]. I have followed the approach described in [this paper on page 6](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.05675.pdf) with the tutorial from [here](https://learnopencv.com/head-pose-estimation-using-opencv-and-dlib/), but the output of my 3D points is not correct at all, the movement of the points is all over the place. Below is my approach using SolvePnP. Am I on the wrong track here, since SolvePnP is normally used for detecting the camera movement (open for other suggestions!) or is my method wrong?

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
array = np.array # convenience

frame1_2d = \
array([[1033.9708251953125 ,  344.23065185546875],
       [1077.796630859375  ,  617.1146240234375 ],
       [ 958.2716674804688 ,  609.1179809570312 ],
       [1074.8084716796875 ,  782.0444946289062 ],
       [ 975.2044067382812 ,  418.1991882324219 ],
       [1024.0103759765625 ,  931.980712890625  ],
       [1122.6185302734375 ,  605.1196899414062 ],
       [1096.721435546875  ,  418.1991882324219 ],
       [ 999.109375        ,  617.1146240234375 ],
       [ 962.255859375     ,  518.1566772460938 ],
       [1111.662109375     ,  517.1571044921875 ],
       [1014.0499877929688 ,  782.0444946289062 ],
       [1061.8599853515625 ,  930.9811401367188 ]])
frame1_3d = \
array([[-0.01265097688883543   , -0.4992150068283081    , -0.11455678939819336   ],
       [ 0.10584918409585953   , -0.0018199272453784943 ,  0.0023642126470804214 ],
       [-0.14271944761276245   ,  0.06332945823669434   ,  0.1438678503036499    ],
       [ 0.09254898130893707   ,  0.3176574409008026    , -0.17930322885513306   ],
       [-0.1155640035867691    , -0.4058316648006439    ,  0.00021289288997650146],
       [-0.03301446512341499   ,  0.6519031524658203    , -0.3515356183052063    ],
       [ 0.14540529251098633   ,  0.05645819008350372   ,  0.10776595026254654   ],
       [ 0.10836226493120193   , -0.4078497290611267    ,  0.000870194286108017  ],
       [-0.10584865510463715   ,  0.001818838994950056  , -0.0023612845689058304 ],
       [-0.1546039581298828    , -0.17418316006660461   ,  0.10266228020191193   ],
       [ 0.1590884029865265    , -0.17913128435611725   ,  0.09423552453517914   ],
       [-0.0736076831817627    ,  0.3179360628128052    , -0.17892584204673767   ],
       [ 0.05236409604549408   ,  0.6490492820739746    , -0.33908188343048096   ]])

frame2_2d = \
array([[1028.110107421875  ,  327.7352600097656 ],
       [1068.0904541015625 ,  606.7128295898438 ],
       [ 982.1328125       ,  229.74314880371094],
       [1071.0889892578125 ,  778.698974609375  ],
       [ 979.13427734375   ,  403.7291564941406 ],
       [1013.1174926757812 ,  933.6865234375    ],
       [1069.0899658203125 ,  243.7420196533203 ],
       [1080.08447265625   ,  403.7291564941406 ],
       [ 997.1254272460938 ,  616.7119750976562 ],
       [ 983.13232421875   ,  312.7364501953125 ],
       [1071.0889892578125 ,  317.7360534667969 ],
       [1005.1214599609375 ,  778.698974609375  ],
       [1061.0938720703125 ,  936.686279296875  ]])

frame2_3d = \
array([[-0.0004756036214530468, -0.5245562791824341   , -0.010652128607034683 ],
       [ 0.10553547739982605  , -0.00272204983048141  ,  0.0024587283842265606],
       [-0.1196068525314331   , -0.6828885078430176   , -0.14210689067840576  ],
       [ 0.0845363438129425   ,  0.38039350509643555  , -0.028144780546426773 ],
       [-0.11286421865224838  , -0.4302292466163635   ,  0.06919233500957489  ],
       [-0.030065223574638367 ,  0.754790186882019    ,  0.012936152517795563 ],
       [ 0.1010960042476654   , -0.6289429664611816   , -0.11814753711223602  ],
       [ 0.1058841198682785   , -0.4253752827644348   ,  0.08086629956960678  ],
       [-0.10553570091724396  ,  0.002716599963605404 , -0.0024500866420567036],
       [-0.127223938703537    , -0.5319695472717285   , -0.09722068160772324  ],
       [ 0.11508879065513611  , -0.49151480197906494  , -0.07002018392086029  ],
       [-0.06679684668779373  ,  0.38714516162872314  , -0.023669833317399025 ],
       [ 0.05081187188625336  ,  0.7544023990631104   , -0.011078894138336182 ]])

frame3_2d = \
array([[1027.91845703125   ,  338.2441711425781 ],
       [1067.8787841796875 ,  612.0115356445312 ],
       [ 803.141357421875  ,  500.10662841796875],
       [1070.8758544921875 ,  776.8713989257812 ],
       [ 968.9768676757812 ,  413.18048095703125],
       [1012.9332885742188 ,  925.7449340820312 ],
       [1248.699462890625  ,  491.1142578125    ],
       [1089.8570556640625 ,  412.18133544921875],
       [ 995.9501342773438 ,  611.0123901367188 ],
       [ 871.073974609375  ,  461.1397399902344 ],
       [1181.765869140625  ,  454.14569091796875],
       [1003.9421997070312 ,  775.8722534179688 ],
       [1061.884765625     ,  933.7380981445312 ]])

frame3_3d = \
array([[-0.003511453978717327  , -0.5015891194343567    , -0.10520103573799133   ],
       [ 0.10480749607086182   , -0.00019206921570003033, -0.0004397481679916382 ],
       [-0.47764456272125244   , -0.1816674768924713    ,  0.04093759506940842   ],
       [ 0.0936243087053299    ,  0.3628539443016052    , -0.09391097724437714   ],
       [-0.11445926129817963   , -0.41107428073883057   ,  0.01644478738307953   ],
       [-0.03567686676979065   ,  0.720417320728302     , -0.10493464022874832   ],
       [ 0.4529808759689331    , -0.18383921682834625   , -0.02210136130452156   ],
       [ 0.1092790886759758    , -0.41095152497291565   ,  0.011709243059158325  ],
       [-0.10480757057666779   ,  0.00018716813065111637,  0.0004445519298315048 ],
       [-0.3031604290008545    , -0.2810187041759491    ,  0.07747684419155121   ],
       [ 0.3006024956703186    , -0.28319910168647766   ,  0.043038371950387955  ],
       [-0.07087739557027817   ,  0.35837966203689575   , -0.08430898934602737   ],
       [ 0.062416717410087585  ,  0.7248380780220032    , -0.13536334037780762   ]])

#frame1_2d = np.asarray(frame1_2d, dtype=float)
#frame1_3d = np.asarray(frame1_3d, dtype=float)
#frame2_2d = np.asarray(frame2_2d, dtype=float)
#frame2_3d = np.asarray(frame2_3d, dtype=float)
#frame3_2d = np.asarray(frame3_2d, dtype=float)
#frame3_3d = np.asarray(frame3_3d, dtype=float)

# Globalize 3D Points
dist_coeffs = (0.11480806073904032, -0.21946985653851792, 0.0012002116999769957, 0.008564577708855225, 0.11274677130853494)
camera_matrix = np.asarray([
    [1394.6027293299926, 0.0, 995.588675691456],
    [0.0, 1394.6027293299926, 599.3212928484164],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1]
])


# create rotation matrix of points
(success, rotation_vector, translation_vector) = cv2.solvePnP(frame3_3d, frame3_2d, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, flags=0)
r_matrix = cv2.Rodrigues(rotation_vector)
rotation_matrix = np.zeros((4, 4))
rotation_matrix[:3, :3], _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rotation_vector)
rotation_matrix[:3, 3] = np.transpose(translation_vector)
rotation_matrix[3, 3] = 1

# apply rotation matrix to points
globalized_3d = np.c_[frame1_3d, np.ones((13, 1))]
for j in range(13):
    globalized_3d[j, :] = np.dot(rotation_matrix, globalized_3d[j, :])
print(globalized_3d)
```

Thanks in advance, appreciate any help!

Edit: Included some examples in my code, after improving the things suggested by top answer

Edit2: Using flag=1 significantly improved the performance/ reduced a lot of the jitter!

Comment: I would have expected the 3D point lists to be equal for all three frames, since those are _model_ points. why would the model's points change?

Comment: It's the person's joint movement, which changes per frame. If you look at the paper i posted on page 5 it's visualized pretty well

Comment: ah okay, so both the 3d and 2d points come from some **pose estimation** algorithm! then I would expect it to deliver 3D points that are **already** in the camera's coordinate frame. they might be normalized in some way though. whatever code you use for the pose estimation would have to document what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes, `solvePnP` is okay to use
2. yes, your math is wrong

I'll assume that you get your points from a face landmark detector, so they have a fixed order. I'll also assume that your 3D model points are given in the same order and their values are consistent and somewhat similar to the face you look at. You should exclude points that denote flesh and mandible (as opposed to skull bone). You actually want to track the skull, not the position of lips and jaws that move all over the place.

`rvec` is an **axis-angle encoding**. Its length is the amount of rotation (expected between 0 and 3.14=pi) and its direction is the axis of rotation.

Use `cv.Rodrigues` to turn the `rvec` into a 3x3 rotation matrix.

In fact, just build yourself some functions that take rvec and tvec and build a 4x4 matrix. Extending all points to be (x,y,z,1) is a hassle but only once.

**And** make sure you use `@` for **matrix multiplication** (or `np.dot`, `np.matmul`, ...) because `*` is **element-wise** multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good to know that at least my approach was right. I fixed my math and sadly the texture still shifts randomly between the Z-Axis very heavily. I have double checked everything and calculations should be correct now. Do you have any ideas what the problem could be? My only possible idea would be that the camera matrix is incorrect (the camera is fixed)

Comment: I'd have to see these results in action, and possibly the code and required input data ([mre]).

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the help already. So I am computing the data from a video and i have picked out 3 frames where the Z Values vary between 3, -3 and 0. Whereas they should stay they same more or less, since no movement is happening in this direction.
Edit: I edited my question to include the code, i haven't really questioned a lot on here